# How many ways can we distribute 50 people in 6 numbered groups? With some conditions!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

50 people with different names, Lorenzo, Sara , Kate , Kevin, ..... should be divided into 6 numbered groups. How many ways can this be done if the groups are to be such that

- none of the groups can be empty and
- Lorenzo and Sara cannot be in the same group and
- Sara and Kate cannot be in the same group.

So we can already see that it's 50 distinct objects into 6 numbered bins.

So my solution to that none of the groups can be empty is. 50!/45! since we only need to fill the first 5 groups with just 1 person, and the remaining group is where i put the rest. So it should be a multinomial coefficient.
50!/1!1!1!1!1!45! = 50!/45!

- Lorenzo and Sara cannot be in the same group and

This is where I get stuck since now I need to fullfill the previous condition. I was thinking of some sort of Principle of Inclusion Eclusion type of problems, but I'm not sure how to set it up.
I was thinking of |Numbers of ways without L&S| = 50!/45! - |Numbers of way with L&S|

Cheers! :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your partial answer of $\frac{50!}{45!}$ is quite wrong.  That only counts the extremely restrictive case of the first five groups getting only a single member but it misses situations like each group getting $9$ or so people.  If it weren't for the extra conditions, it would have been $6^{50}$ outcomes... a completely different calculation than the one you proposed.

Comment: As for continuing, yes... inclusion-exclusion is the typical way to do this.  You want that "Group1 is not empty", and "Group2 is not empty",..., and "L and S are not in the same group", and "S and K are not in same group".  So you want to avoid those where "Group1 is empty" or "Group 2 is empty" or ... or "L and S are in same group" or "S and K are in same group."  Apply inclusion-exclusion over these.

Comment: Your totally correct about that one. Then the wisest thing to do from here on is tackling all 3 conditions at the same time. My staggered approach might not have been the best.

Comment: So All 3 conditions fullfilled would be 6^50 - (None Empty U L&S U S&K)

Comment: This by itself is quite challenging for me to start :/

Comment: (All Empty U L&S Together U S&K together) = |All Empty| + |S&K| +|L&S| - (all unions of 2 combination) + (All 3 at the same time)

Comment: Starting with all empty. Hmm... I would say that you're doing 50 choose 0 six times. So 6* 50C0. Edit: Actually nvm this only gives me 6. Somehow feels wrong

Comment: The opposite of "None empty" is not "All empty".  The correct opposite of "None empty" is "*At least one* empty" which is equivalent to "Group1 empty or Group2 empty or group3 empty or..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inclusion-exclusion over the events "Group1 is empty", "Group2 is empty", ... , "Group6 is empty" but keep track of all events *including* the events "L and S in same group" and "K and S in same group."  For convenience sake, write out all where we had neither of these final two events first... then follow it by where we had exactly one of these final two events, and lastly do it where we had both.

$\left(6^{50}-\binom{6}{1}5^{50}+\binom{6}{2}4^{50}-\binom{6}{3}3^{50}+\binom{6}{4}2^{50}-\binom{6}{5}1^{50}\right) - 2\left(6^{49}-\binom{6}{1}5^{49}+\binom{6}{2}4^{49}-\binom{6}{3}3^{49}+\binom{6}{4}2^{49}-\binom{6}{5}1^{49}\right) +\left(6^{48}-\binom{6}{1}5^{48}+\binom{6}{2}4^{48}-\binom{6}{3}3^{48}+\binom{6}{4}2^{48}-\binom{6}{5}1^{48}\right)$

Recognize that each of these parenthetical phrases matches the answer to the problem had we ignored these final two events and that these can be simplified using stirling numbers of the second kind:

$({50 \brace 6} - 2{49\brace 6} + {48 \brace 6})6! = 560965392866494641023205785898674256720$

Compare this to the approximation by trueblueanil's probability argument of it being $\frac{5^2}{6^2}{50\brace 6} = 560936381547005993727389118856408343500$, an error of approximately $0.005\%$

The take away is that one should be careful about assuming independence and uniformity, but with numbers as large as these one could and should expect that the error caused by such an assumption should be miniscule.  It is still an error however.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see the whole picture. I never connected the whole permutation stirling to distinct boxes until recently. The only thing that lingers on my mind is the alternating + and -. I think I read it somewhere, but not sure where 

Comment: I know it's part of the process of PIE, removing double counting. But, is it always a alternating pattern?
And I mean by within the parameter. 
6^50−(6C1)5^50+(6C2)4^50−(6C3)3^50+(6C4)2^50−(6C5)1^50)

Comment: @CapybaraHideout yes, it is always alternating.

Comment: I'm sorry for bringing up an old post. But this atleast/exactly word has been on my mind regarding PIE. 
Is it fair to see them as pairs?

Since I'm guessing we're doing the operation: 
exactly i = (atleast i) - (atleast i + 1) 
multiple times over, which makes it look like it "alternating"

Comment: Not exactly... I suggest looking at a proof of inclusion-exclusion.  Start with the two-set version.  Notice that $|A\cup B| = |A\setminus B|+|A\cap B|+|B\setminus A|$ and also notice that $|A|=|A\setminus B|+|A\cap B|$, similarly for $|B|$, but to have an extra $|A\cap B|$ to add to make the $|B|$ we'll need to balance it out by subtracting it as well... giving $|A\cup B|=(|A\setminus B|+|A\cap B|)+(|B\setminus A|+|A\cap B|)-|A\cap B| = |A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$.

Comment: @CapybaraHideout now, you can complete by induction hopefully, noting that $A\cup B\cup C = (A\cup B)\cup C$, performing the two-set version where the first "set" is $(A\cup B)$ and the second set is $C$, and then in what results breaking down the $(A\cup B)$'s that appear.  Similarly if talking about $A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots \cup A_n$ breaking it up as $(A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots \cup A_{n-1})\cup A_n$ and using induction hypothesis as necessary.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/D1k4Lz7
Not sure how to insert pictures. So I decided to upload it on imgur instead. It's the highlighted part that I can't seem to grasp. I greatly appreciate ur patience 

Comment: I'm probably interpreting it wrong, but can this be seen as some sort of nestled principle of inclusion exclusion? Since we're dealing with multiple conditions

Comment: The two set inclusion-exclusion is $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$.  The five-set inclusion-exclusion is $|A\cup B\cup C\cup D\cup E| = \underbrace{|A|+\dots+|E|}_{\text{all singles}}\underbrace{-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-\dots}_{\text{all pairs}} \underbrace{+|A\cap B\cap C|+\dots}_{\text{all triples}} \underbrace{-|A\cap B\cap C\cap D|-\dots}_{\text{all quadruples}}\underbrace{+|A\cap \dots\cap E|}_{\text{all quintuples}}$

Comment: And in general, for all $k$ we have all $k$-tuples appearing and this is either added or subtracted depending on the parity of $k$